# How to stop the Tomcat6 server?

Tags: tomcat

I am using Ubuntu. Even when I try to stop tomcat it keeps on running. For example:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 stop
```

The above does not stop it, even though it reports its status as `stopped`. If I visit the URL `https://localhost:8080` it is still running. Please help.

Comment: do you have something running that depends on tomcat running that needs to be stopped 1st?

Answer (score 0):

**To stop the service use below command**

```
sudo service tomcat6 stop
```

or (if you need a restart)

```
sudo tomcat6 restart
```

**To kill the process use below steps**

1. In terminal, run:

`fuser -n tcp 8080`

2. Now we got some output like this:

`8080/tcp:   12345`

3. Here 123456 is the process id. Kill that using:

`kill -9 12345`

**Alternatively**, you can get tomcat process id by using

```
ps -ef |grep 'catalina'
```

Comment: I would assume there to be a reason for tomcat not to just stop. Killing it can have consequences.

Comment: @Rinzwind, Thanks for the comment. I have updated my answer.